# How can I get Haml to render the contents of a pre tag correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I read the Haml [docs](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/docs/rdoc/classes/Haml.html) where they talk about the `pre` tag and "preserving whitespace". According to the docs, `pre` "preserves whitespace" by default and you need to use the `~` operator to output the contents of the tag to get it to render correctly. Following the recommended practice, I have this:

```
%pre
  ~ @calendar.main_template
```

The output in the browser:

(This may be a little confusing -- the app is letting the user manipulate Haml code, so I'm actually displaying Haml code here in the UI.)

```
%div
                = events
```

What output want:

```
%div
  = events
```

I also tried using `=` instead of `~`. Also tried `%pre>`, `%pre<`, and `%pre><` all with identical results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `preserve`.

```
%pre
  = preserve "I like\n  Cheese"
```